# In angularjs we are having ng-disabled directive, why ng-enabled directive is not provided by the framework as we are having ng-show and ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJs `ng-enabled` directive is not provided. Is there any proper reason to not providing that directive in the framework, because we are having both `ng-show` and `ng-hide` when you can just use `ng-hide` to achieve our goal.

It wouldn't be nice just to check 
    **`ng-enabled="attribute.value === true"`**

instead of
    **`ng-disabled="!(attribute.value === true)"`**

it will increase the readability of the code.

Comment: It was really a good question, thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/btford/angular-enabled

Comment: Either `ng-disabled="attribute.value !== true"` or `ng-disabled="!attribute.value"` would be more significantly more readable than `ng-disabled="!(attribute.value === true)"`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The reason why there is no `ngEnabled` directive in Angular is rather semantical - there is simply nothing corresponding to it in HTML specification. At the same time there is already `ngDisabled` directive that works with `disabled` attribute. For the same reason, there is no `ngUnchecked` directive, because there is already `ngChecked` that sets/removes `checked` attribute.

Now, the reasonable question: why we have both `ngShow` and `ngHide` then? Well it's just for convenience in this case I guess, because having both `ngShow` and `ngHide` is not more confusing than `ngShow` alone, but at the same time it's very handy to have both.

Comment: I've read somewhere (can't remember where though) that the Angular devs thinks it's a mistake to have both ng-show and ng-hide because it makes the logic harder both for the implementors and the users.

What if you use both ng-show and ng-hide on the same element and they both evaluate to "true", which one should apply?

Sure, you should not do that, but the library should not make it easy for you to do those mistakes.

Comment: I agree with the point that it can be confusing. If it was up to me I would only ship `ngHide`.

Comment: The answer makes good sense, but personally I follow the 'affirmative' boolean naming convention which avoids double negatives.  ngHide with a negatively named boolean set to false should cause a few headscratches.  I am well aware this is personal preference.

Comment: i am a hard anti-fan of two different words for the opposite singular concept.
good and ungood is actually great, despite its anti-humanistic connotations imbued by 1984. We have words like and dislike, and we have no problem. hate is not always the opposite of like. you can not like and also not hate. the opposite of like is dislike and the opposite of hate is dishate. "dis" in programming is simply shebang ! or negation. It's much more clearer and elegant that way. It also helps with searching because the way search works.

Comment: @aaaaaa as long as the concept is truly boolean, not quaternary, absolutey. dislike means to not like, but not liking something doesn't necessarily mean you hate it. you can also not hate it either. 1 like, 2 not like, 3 hate, 4 not hate. quaternary.

Answer (score 12):

I am not missing an ng-enabled directive at all and I think it would add little to nothing to the framework.

Inputs are enabled by default and HTML inputs also do not have an enabled attribute, just a disabled. The angular directive sets the HTML disabled attribute, but after evaluating an expression.

You can just write

> ng-disabled="!attribute.value"

I think it is pretty readable.

Comment: Compare sentences "thing is disabled when it is not 1, 2 or 3" with "thing is enabled when its 1, 2 or 3". It takes a lot more brain power to parse the first one, and the second one just clicks.

Comment: It's an unnecessary double negative.  However, now that we have ng-disabled, introducing ng-enabled too (and removing other double negatives?) would be too proliferative.

Answer (score 5):

### TLDR:  Use [angular-enabled](https://github.com/btford/angular-enabled) instead.

The core team expressed their view in this this comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1252#issuecomment-49261373

They will not abide a feature request just because it has many +1-s in order to keep the core bloat free.

However, if you still want to have ng-enabled functionality, btford has created this handy little module just for you:
https://github.com/btford/angular-enabled

Answer (score 4):

Angular sets the disabled attribute based on the result of the expression in ng-disabled. There is no enabled attribute in HTML5 so ng-Enabled wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This line worked for me.

```
ng-disabled="!attribute.value"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that this is an answer to the question of *Why* but for those who want to write their own directive, here you go. BTW it's in *coffeescript*.

```
.directive 'ngEnabled', [
    '$parse'
    ($parse)->

      dir =
        restrict: 'AC'
        link: ($scope, elem, attrs)->
          getter = $parse attrs.ngEnabled

          $off = $scope.$watch ->
            getter $scope
          , (val)->
            elem.attr 'disabled', !val

          $scope.$on '$destroy', -> $off()
  ]
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/F4RG2v859oFtTumvgoGN?p=preview